# Using bit manipulations, return word with all odd-numbered bits set to 1

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, cpu-word

This problem is part of a larger coding project in my coding class, intro to C. The goal of the project is to get used to bit manipulations and floating point. To do so, it presents a number of problems under restrictions. Here is this problem:

```
 /* 
 * OddBits - return word with all odd-numbered bits set to 1
 *   Legal operations: | <<
 *   Max operations: 6
 *   Rating: 2
 */
```

As you can see, for his problem, I can only use | and <<. There are some other assumptions as well not listed in this problem. They are; no constants bigger than 0xFF, assume 32 bit machine, and no statements such as do, if, while, or else. Also I **can't** cast variables into unsigned.

Here is my current code:

```
int OddBits(void) {
  int x;
  return (x | (x << 1)) | ((x << 1) << 1);
}
```

The error message thrown by the grading software is:

```
ERROR: Test OddBits() failed...
...Gives 0[0x0]. Should be -1431655766[0xaaaaaaaa]
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain where I went wrong with my methodology and how I could fix it.

Comment: What is the initial value of `x` ? A good place to start...

Comment: probably you want `return 0xaa | (0xaa << 8) | (0xaa << 16) | (0xaa << 24);` - 6 operations

Comment: @Fe2O3 I'm not sure. There is no main function on this assignment, and global variables aren't allowed. Do I need to assign a value to the variable?

Comment: Too bad you can't use division: `(-1U/3)<<1`

Comment: "_Do I need to assign a value to the variable?_" If you don't, you have no idea what the uninitialised value may be. There is a very, very small chance that the value may be exactly 0xaaaaaaaa and there is nothing else to be done. (This is very, very unlikely.)

Comment: @aschepler unfortunately not, just left shift (<<) and or (|)

Comment: Yes, you need to assign a value before it makes sense to use the value (otherwise, what value gets used? not something you control). By the way you can solve this in 4 operations too.

Comment: @harold 4 operations? how is that possible? And more importantly why does it work?

Comment: Shouldn't you solve this homework? The key to using 4 operations is concatenating a value with itself twice. Once to lengthen it from 8 bits to 16 bits, then again from 16 bits to 32 bits.

Comment: @harold Perhaps a `union`? Initialise 4 single bytes in one statement, no other operations required. `:-)` (Endian indifferent, too!)

Comment: return 0xaaaaaaaa; one operation

Comment: @0___________ "no constants bigger than 0xFF".

Comment: If the assignment `=` is not allowed, the code cannot use a variable. (Otherwise I would have has a nifty improvement on the proposal by Ikya.

Comment: As @Fe2O3 stated before. Take a closer look at your 'x'. Really start with that. It's really hard to determine what 'x' is. It depends on the compiler you used and the current order of planets. Set it to the value you want. Which is...?

Comment: Concerning if and how variables are initialized: Your course material and accompanied literature should have enough information. If not, drop the course. If you did not read it, I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, this will help:

```
int OddBits(void) {
  return 0x55 | (0x55 << 8) | (0x55 << 16) | (0x55 << 24);
}
```

Comment: Since the expected value is 0xAAAAAAAA, this is _nearly_ correct. :-D